# In Swift, does Int have a hidden initializer that takes a String?

Tags: swift

I tried looking at the Swift API for Int, and I'm still not sure why this works:

```
var foo = Int("100")
```

I see the following initializers in the documentation:

```
init()
init(_: Builtin.Word)
init(_: Double)
init(_: Float)
init(_: Int)
init(_: Int16)
init(_: Int32)
init(_: Int64)
init(_: Int8)
init(_: UInt)
init(_: UInt16)
init(_: UInt32)
init(_: UInt64)
init(_: UInt8)
init(_:radix:)
init(_builtinIntegerLiteral:)
init(bigEndian:)
init(bitPattern:)
init(integerLiteral:)
init(littleEndian:)
init(truncatingBitPattern: Int64)
init(truncatingBitPattern: UInt64)
```

But I don't see a `init(_: String)` above.  Is there some automagic that happens under the hood?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a

```
extension Int {
    /// Construct from an ASCII representation in the given `radix`.
    ///
    /// If `text` does not match the regular expression
    /// "[+-][0-9a-zA-Z]+", or the value it denotes in the given `radix`
    /// is not representable, the result is `nil`.
    public init?(_ text: String, radix: Int = default)
}
```

extension method taking a string and an optional radix (which is 10 by default):

```
var foo = Int("100") // Optional(100)
var bar = Int("100", radix: 2) // Optional(4)
var baz = Int("44", radix: 3) // nil
```

*How could one find that?* Using the "trick" from
["Jump to definition" for methods without external parameter names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048978/jump-to-definition-for-methods-without-external-parameter-names), write the equivalent
code

```
var foo = Int.init("100")
//            ^^^^
```

and then <kbd>cmd</kbd>-click on `init` in Xcode :)

Comment: Nice thanks!  Do you know why this might be left out of their documentation?  Are methods defined in this way special or different from those listed in the docs?

Comment: @SkalleyWagg: Actually it is there, and you have even copied it into your question (which I did not notice until now :). It is `init(_:radix:)`.

Comment: Ah.  How is this read?  I thought what follows the colon is the data type.  I would've imagined it would be defined more like: `init(_:String, radix:Int)`

Comment: @SkalleyWagg: Well yes, and that is what you see e.g. in the Xcode Quick Help. I *assume* that the import to the documentation is not optimal and not consistent. In `init(truncatingBitPattern: Int64)` the type of the parameter is given, but in `init(littleEndian:)` it is not. If you are really curious, file a bug report at Apple!

Comment: Got it!  I was just worried there was some syntax shorthand I didn't understand yet.  Thank you very much for your tutelage.